# Correct way to export a DLL function on Mac OSX

Tags: macos, dll, dllexport

I'm trying to compile a simple DLL on a Mac OS X 10.6, and am confused about the proper way to declare a function that the DLL offers up for the world to use.   Following sample code from a reliable source, I came up with:

```
__declspsec(dllexport) pascal int ReturnTheNumberFive(void)
```

but gcc barfs on it.   What the sample code actually had was MACPASCAL and DLLExport, which I assumed were macros.  I grepped through the sample codes, SDKs, etc for #defines and plugged in what I found.   These definitions could have been buried inside #ifs, so what I found isn't good and true.  Illogically, the compiler also barfs if I just do the obvious and use DLLExport and MACPASCAL, so that's no solution.

What is the correct way to make a DLL's function available to apps?

Comment: On Mac, a 'DLL' is not called a DLL; the file itself is called `.dylib` and it's often embedded in a `.framework`. It's not just a nitpicking on terminology... I guess without the usual words used in the community, it's harder to google for the info! So, please use the word `dylib` and `framework` from now on.

Comment: What those of us who are suddenly finding ourselves in the Mac programming world is a Guide for Newcomers that really explains all that.  For now, it's bits and pieces such as your comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, all symbols are visible in a `.dylib`. There are no calling convention changes (such as Pascal calling convention)

So, in short:

`int ReturnTheNunmberFive(void) { return 6; }`

Comment: The DLLExport and MACPASCAL are apparently for portability to other platforms.  It's not explained anywhere that I, as a foreigner in the Land of Apple, could find, that these evalutate to nothingness.  Well, now I know!