# C# : Pass string array to c++ dll / dylib

Tags: c#, c++, macos

I'm having trouble passing in an array of strings from my c# code to a function from my c++ dylib.

C# code:

```
[DllImport("array2d.dylib", EntryPoint = "process_array", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public static extern int process_array(String[] a, int b);
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        String[] list = new String[] { "Abc" , "def", "ghi", "jkl"};
        int josh = process_array(list, 2);                          
     }
```

My C++ code:

```
 #include <string>
#include <iostream>



int process_array(char** array, int rows)
{

    std::string s1 ("Array : [");

        for (int i = 0; i < 6; ++i){
                s1.append(array[i]);
                s1.append(", ");

        }
        s1.append("] \n");


        return 1;

}

int main()
{

}
```

And the error I have been getting is:

Unhandled Exception: System.EntryPointNotFoundException: Unable to find an entry point named 'process_array' in DLL 'array2d.dylib'.
   at JoshServer.Program.process_array(String[] a, Int32 b)

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Does your cpp file export any function? There must be some keywords like dllexport. Read about creating dlls in cpp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function in your C++ program is not being exported:

```
int process_array(char** array, int rows)
```

You must mark it with dllexport, like this:

```
extern "C" int process_array(char** array, int rows)
```

Update: This [project](https://github.com/ichramm/pinvokeTalk) contains the examples used in a talk I gave a while  ago about PInvoke, I hope it helps.

Some corrections.

```
 for (int i = 0; i < 6; ++i){
```

Should be:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i){
```

And

```
int josh = process_array(list, 2);
```

Should be

```
int josh = process_array(list, list.Length);
```

**Updated:** Removed `__declspec(dllexport)` (osx) and added some corrections.

Comment: I'm on a mac and the compiler goes crazy when I add that. From what I read it says to take it out? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6838222/correct-way-to-export-a-dll-function-on-mac-osx?rq=1

Comment: Hi there, sorry I didn't realize you were in a mac. Would you mind trying to add the `extern "C"` expression to the function?